# Are Svelte transitions/animations done with CSS or JS?

Tags: svelte, svelte-transition

I'm checking out Svelte, and I'm finding a lot more out of the box that I would've expected.

One thing that surprised me a little bit where the amount of transition and animation tools, especially the tooling for [custom transitions](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-css-transitions), and I can't quite tell from their syntax if these are functions that write CSS, or if they're functions that manipulate styles directly with a CSS-like syntax.

Are the resulting animations CSS only or not?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short answer: CSS.

The longer answer: When a transition function is called, it returns an object with the transition object, which must include a `css` method, a `tick` method, or both. The `tick` method is straightforward — it is called every frame (using `requestAnimationFrame`, essentially) until the transition has completed, allowing you do things that are impossible just with CSS, like a [typewriter effect](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-js-transitions).

The `css` method works differently. Say you have a simple fade transition that returns a function like this:

```js
css: t => `opacity: ${t}`
```

(This is almost exactly what the [built-in fade transition does](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/bc4bd8a4387d0c5dcdeadb10ca3ce0d982c531d3/transition.mjs#L13).) This function will be called multiple times with a different value of `t` *before* the transition begins — the number of times depends on the duration of the transition — so that a set of keyframes are generated:

```js
keyframes = [
  '0% { opacity: 0 }',
  '10% { opacity: 0.1 }',
  '20% { opacity: 0.2 }',
  // ...
];
```

Those keyframes are then joined together into a CSS animation and applied to the element.

In that simple example, it might seem over-engineered — after all, we could just go from `0% { opacity: 0 }` to `100% { opacity: 1 }`. But it gives us the power to build [custom transitions](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-css-transitions) with easing functions that aren't normally available in CSS animations, all without resorting to manipulating styles in JavaScript (which must happen on the main thread, creating a common source of jank.)

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: if I understand you correctly, a `tick` method will manipulate styles in JavaScript but it is there to provide effects CSS itself simply cannot do?

Comment: It can manipulate styles, or change some state, or log something to the console — whatever you want. It's just there as an escape hatch for when CSS isn't powerful enough.